# Using Memoir class with RMarkdown fails when trying to generate the table of contents

Tags: memoir, rstudio, rmarkdown

I am using `RMarkdown` in `RStudio` to compile a book written in Markdown. I am using the memoir class and it all works fine as long as I set `toc: false`. When I try to compile with toc I get the followin error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...link}{\Hy@tocdestname }{\tocchapter 
                                                  {Chapter}{1}{Βασικές Έννοι...
l.1 ...Chapter}{1}{Βασικές Έννοιες}}{5}{chapter.1}
                                                  %
```

I don't really know much about latex so I am at a loss on how to debug this. Would be grateful for any pointers.

EDIT: Looking around after @daleif 's suggestion I found that the text in the error is from a `.toc` file. It contains three lines:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\tocchapter {Chapter}{1}{Βασικές Έννοιες}}{5}{chapter.1}%
\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{1}{Το Ηχητικό Κύμα: Συχνότητα \& Πλάτος}}{5}{section.1.1}%
\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{2}{Το Πεδίο του Χρόνου}}{6}{section.1.2}%
```

Comment: Please show the generated .tex file. `\tocchapter` is not a known command from `memoir` so we need to know what else you are inserting into this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @daleif . I 've added the tex file.

Comment: @daleif I found that `\tocchapter` was in a `.toc` file so I attached that as well.

Comment: @daleif OK, I solved it! the `.toc` file must have been left from a compilation before I started using the memoir class. Deleting it fixed the error! Thank you!

Comment: Please note that we generally does not like to go to external sites to get log or tex code as links rot over time and thus your question will not make any sense for others in the future.

Comment: @daleif I agree but the text was too long  What is the preferred way to include it?

Comment: Put it into your question like with contentsline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.toc` file must have been leftover from a previous compilation without the memoir class. Deleting the file fixed the issue.